# Is there any stripe test card with fixed balance?

Tags: testing, stripe-payments, card

I am searching for a stripe test card with fixed balance. For example, a stripe test card with $50

I have searched for Stripe test card with fixed balance but did not get any. It would helpful for my testing purpose. I need a stripe test card with fixed balance

Comment: Stripe doesn't provide a test card with fixed balance. If you wish to test insufficient fund flow, there is a `Insufficient funds decline` test card with `4000 0000 0000 9995` for it: https://stripe.com/docs/testing#declined-payments